# WebStorm list files with unresolved imports

Tags: webstorm

After some refactoring I somehow ended up with many dependent files not being updated in their import paths.

When opening the files themselves I get highlighted import paths that failed to resolve, however I'd like to get a list of all files that contain unresolved import paths.

The `find usages` functionality is not sufficient here, because I moved more than one file and therefore end up with manual search again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run **Code | Inspect Code** for your project and then check all **JavaScript and TypeScript | General | File references validation** errors in the **Inspection Results** tool window

[image]